# Looking for something like OrElse in angular rxjs find function while piping

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I have got the following piece of code. What I am trying to achieve is to redirect to the page not found when "find" function does not find any order object in the observable loaded orders.

```
private order: Observable<OrderModel>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.name = params.id;
    this.order = this.orderService.ordersLoaded.pipe(map((orders: OrderModel[]) => orders
          .find((order: OrderModel) => order.orderName === this.name.toUpperCase())));
 });
```

I have tried something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.name = params.id;
    this.order = this.orderService.ordersLoaded.pipe(map((orders: OrderModel[]) => orders
        .find((order: OrderModel) => order.orderName === this.name.toUpperCase()),
        defaultIfEmpty(this.router.navigate(['/notFound']))
      ));
 });
```

But it always redirects me to the page not found component.

Answer (score 0):

You can you tap operator to archive what you want:

```
this.order = this.orderService.ordersLoaded.pipe(
      map((orders: OrderModel[]) => orders.find(order => order.orderName === this.name.toUpperCase()),
      tap(order => {
        if (!order) {
          this.router.navigate(['/notFound']);
        }
      })
    ));
```

You can create a few custom rxjs operators to get rid of `if`:

```
export function tapIf<T>(
  predicate: (value: T) => boolean,
  fn: (x: T) => void
): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return input$ =>
    input$.pipe(
      tap(x => {
        if (predicate(x)) {
          fn(x);
        }
      })
    );
}

export function tapIfFalsy<T>(fn: (x: T) => void): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return tapIf<T>(x => !x, x => fn(x));
}
```

then you code can become even simpler:

```
this.order = this.orderService.ordersLoaded.pipe(
      map((orders: OrderModel[]) => orders.find(order => order.orderName === this.name.toUpperCase()),
      tapIfFalsy(() => this.router.navigate(['/notFound']))
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

`defaultIfEmpty()` actually only fire when the observable completed but nothing is returned, 
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/conditional/defaultifempty.html
it has nothing to do with the value returned

You can try the code below

```
zip(this.orderService.ordersLoaded,this.route.params).pipe(tap([orders,params])=>{
  this.name = params.id;
  if(!orders.find(order=>order.orderName === this.name.toUpperCase())
        this.router.navigate(['/notFound'])
}).subscribe()
```

Comment: Don't use zip, it won't emit second value, if it's needed.

Comment: Yes but above code will emit, even http timeout will emit an error

Comment: there're combine latest\forkjoin operators. Zip is completely unacceptable in this scenario. If you stay on the same component with router params being changed, you won't get the code above being refetched

Comment: if it is a continuous stream, then we change back to switchMap approach which makes more sense

Comment: I mean that using zip doesn't make any sense since it doesn't add any useful behavior and may result in undesired things if the logic is being changed.